# How can i transform $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: 0 <Im(z) <1\}/[0,i/2]$ to $\{ z \in \mathbb{C} Im(z)>0\}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, transformation, conformal-geometry

it would be direct by $e^{\pi z}$ if we didn't have that finite slit in the imaginary axe, so how can i deal with that slit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is slightly complicated.
I explain the solution step-by-step.

First step:
The function $e^{\pi z}$ maps $$D=\{z\in \mathbb{C}: 0<\operatorname{Im}\, z<1\}\setminus [0,i/2]$$ to $$E=\{z\in \mathbb{C}: 
 0<\operatorname{Im}\, z\}\setminus \{z\in\mathbb{C}: z=e^{i\theta },0\le \theta \le \pi/2\}.$$
$E$ is the upper half plane with a circular slit in the first quadrant.

Second step:  **This is a renewal**.
The old one is not so easy. It is to be erased.
Let $\varphi (z)=\frac{z-1}{z+1}.$
Note that $\varphi $ maps the upper half plane to the upper half plane and the image of the circular slit $\{z\in\mathbb{C}: z=e^{i\theta },0\le \theta \le \pi/2\}$ by $\varphi $ is the line segment $[0,i]$.
Hence we see that $\varphi $ maps $E$ to $F=\{z\in\mathbb{C}: \operatorname{Im}z>0\}\setminus [0,i]$.
($\varphi$ and $F$ are changed.)

Third step:
Let $\phi(z)=\sqrt{z},$  where $\sqrt{z}$ is defined in $\mathbb{C}\setminus [0,\infty)$ so that 
$$\sqrt{re^{i\theta }}=\sqrt{r}e^{i\frac{\theta }{2}},\quad z=re^{i\theta }, 0\le \theta <2\pi.$$
Then $\phi(z^2+1)=\sqrt{z^2+1}$ maps $F$ to the upper half plane.

Comment: so then i should transform this using $1/z$ to transform this into a region delimited by two line without slits?

Comment: So now, i should now take this to the upper half plane with a infinite slit in the imaginary axis, then use $z^2$ to take that to all $\mathbb{C}$ with a infinite slit in the real line so a use a mobius to take in $\mathbb{C}/[0,\infty]$ take a branch with $\sqrt(z)$ and get to the upper half plane

Comment: i'm taking some calculations here and i noticed that the imaginary part under this transformation by this circular slit will not always be $0$, so how can it be $[0,1]??$

Comment: I'm sorry. $\varphi$ is changed. This new version is easier than the old, perhaps.

Comment: Sorry, but i still can't see why the image of this circular slit up this transformation is a straight line, take $\sqrt(2)/2 + i\sqrt(2)/2$ and look in this transformation

Comment: For $z=e^{i\theta }$ $(0\le \theta \le \pi/2)$ \begin{align}
\varphi (z)&=\frac{e^{i\theta }-1}{e^{i\theta }+1}=\frac{\cos\theta -1+i\sin\theta }{\cos\theta +1+i\sin\theta}\\
&=\frac{(\cos\theta -1+i\sin\theta )(\cos\theta +1-i\sin\theta)}{(\cos\theta +1+i\sin\theta)(\cos\theta +1-i\sin\theta)}=i\frac{\sin\theta }{1+\cos\theta }\in [0,i].
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

The Möbius transformation $\varphi(z)=\frac{z-1}{z+1}$ doesn't map the upper half plane to the upper half plane because determinant = $(ad-bc)\neq1$.